# Chrome Mobile API?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome

I want to build an application similar to Diet Coda, so I can have a preview of a webpage I am working on. For this I wanted to use Google Chrome Mobile and not a WebView. I was wondering if Google Chrome Mobile had some functions I could call to periodically reload the page or interact with the browser from a Service. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using WebKit's debugging protocol.
Check out this reference page: [1.0:Page - Chrome Developer Tools -- Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/page)
There's a function called "reload" you can use to reload the page remotely.

For more generic remote debugging information, check out this page: [Debugger Protocol - Chrome Developer Tools -- Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol)
You'll need some preparations such as installing Android SDK to connect to the device by using adb in order to make remote debugging feature enabled.